# also include records in this table that match condition on another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have tables in these lines:

A:

```
id   param_1   param_2    status     dateUpdated
-----------------------------------------------
1    valuea   valueb    Active      2018-10-02
2    valuec   valued    Inactive    2018-09-03
3    valuee   valuef    Active      2018-10-01
4    valueg   valueh    Active      2017-01-20
5    value1   value2    Active      2018-03-03
6    value3   value4    Active      2016-10-21
...
```

B:

```
id    a_id   some_param    dateModified
-------------------------------------
1     3      x             2018-10-04 
2     2      y             2018-06-30
3     4      aa            2018-10-01
...
99    6      ab            2018-01-16
100   3      z             2018-04-08
```

I want records in `A` that were updated after a certain date but also includes other records(if not already present, otherwise return latest date) that match a date condition from another table `B`.

if only table `A`:

```
select id,
       param_1, 
       param_2, 
       dateUpdated
from A
where status = 'Active'
and dateUpdated between @someDate and @someAnotherDate
```

Now with join:

```
select distinct  A.id,
                 A.param_1, 
                 A.param_2, 
                 A.dateUpdated -- or B.dateModified, whichever is latest if that's even possible
from A
join B on B.a_id = A.id
where A.status = 'Active'
and ((A.dateUpdated between @someDate and @someAnotherDate) || (B.dateModified between @someDate and @someAnotherDate))
```

So from the above, say for `someDate = '2018-10-01'` and `someAnotherDate = '2018-10-04'` I would have result:

```
id,  param_1   param_2    dateUpdated
------------------------------------
1    valuea   valueb      2018-10-02
3    valuee   valuef      2018-10-04
4    valueg   valueh      2018-10-01
```

Comment: Would you include the A record with ID 3, if its date were not in the range? I.e. would it suffice that there is a record in B for a_id 3 with such a date?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've updated the question to include 4, 5, and 6. I guess that should cater for almost all possible scenarios. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Okay. I've already updated my answer. With the altered `WHERE` clause I am showing, you'll also get ID 4.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!. I'll try the answers as soon as I get another chance to sit down.

Comment: Could you explain the criteria again? From what I see is that you want row 1 and 3 which satisfy the condition directly, but upon joining there will be two rows for 3. Which one do you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `B` you want the maximum date in the given range per `a_id`. Outer join this result to `A` and use `CASE WHEN` to get the newer date.

```
select
  a.id,
  a.param_1,
  a.param_2,
  a.status,
  case when bmax.max_date > a.dateUpdated then bmax.max_date else a.dateUpdated as updated
from a
left join
(
  select a_id, max(dateModified) as max_date
  from b
  where dateModified between @someDate and @someAnotherDate
  group by a_id
) bmax on bmax.a_id = a.id
where a.status = 'Active'
and 
(
   a.dateUpdated between @someDate and @someAnotherDate
   or
   bmax.dateModified between @someDate and @someAnotherDate
)
order by a.id;
```

Comment: a quick question. Wouldn't the correct range already be selected for  `select a_id, max(dateModified) as max_date ..`. Should we include the filtering again in `where` clause? i.e. `bmax.dateModified between @someDate and @someAnotherDate`

Comment: Yes we must, because bmax is outer joined.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and case expression for getting latest date

```
select distinct  A.id,
                 A.param_1, 
                 A.param_2, 
                 case when A.dateUpdated > B.dateUpdated
                 then A.dateUpdated else B.dateUpdated end

from A
left join B on B.a_id = A.id
where A.status = 'Active'
and ((A.dateUpdated between @someDate and @someAnotherDate) 
    OR (B.dateModified between @someDate and @someAnotherDate))
```